# Discord.js how can i get user nickname using the user's id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using client.on('voiceStateUpdate...) to check when a user has left or joined a voice channel, and it sends a message of the user as an '@<\id>' which pings them.

The pings have been upsetting them and I'm trying to find a way in which it sends a message of the nickname without @ (msg.replace('@','') doesn't work).

What can I do to get the nickname of the user if I already have the user's ID?

My code now looks like this:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel;
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel;
  var channel = client.channels.get('385344314362036224');
  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    channel.sendMessage(newMember + ' has joined a voice channel');
  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
    channel.sendMessage(oldMember + ' has left a voice channel');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oldMember and newMember are of the type "GuildMember". You can find everything you can do using a GuildMember here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember

So your code to use the nickname should look like this:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel;
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel;
  var channel = client.channels.get('385344314362036224');
  if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    channel.sendMessage(newMember.displayName + ' has joined a voice channel');
  } else if(newUserChannel === undefined){
    channel.sendMessage(oldMember.displayName + ' has left a voice channel');
  }
});
```

Comment: newMember.nickname will return null if they don't have a nickname

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed it to displayName which will default to the username if no nickname is found.

Comment: Didn't knew about displayName. i've deleted my answer